# Angular within Bootstrap remote tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a basic angular page, it pulls some records from a database and displays in a `table` via `ng-repeat` - this is working fine as a standalone page.

I'm using bootstrap remote tabs https://github.com/thecodeassassin/bootstrap-remote-data and am calling the above page as one of the tabs'  content.  The angular page is loaded but angular is not initialising though for some reason.  Nothing is binding.

I've tried putting the angular scripts both inside / outside of the tab, and also putting `ngApp` inside of the tab (remote page) and outside of the tab (parent page) and it doesn't make any difference.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I suppose my option is to display it in an iframe instead?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I think the problem is that the angular finishes the loop for initializing the content before the pages are loaded inside the tabs.

have you tried to use ng-include to load the content of the tabs dynamically.

also you may need to call for angular apply to re initiate the binding.

another note, if you are trying to use the tabs to load the data asynchronously, you can use regular tabs and let angular handles the loading of the data using ng-include.